# Personalization strings problems

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, attribute

I want to set up personalization strings on a email in marketing cloud salesforce from several data extensions without going through AMPScript. Is there a friendly way to use attributes from multiple data extensions without coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fields he that exist in the send DE , you can use a personalisation string e.g. %%FirstName%% (when first name contains the first name of the recipient in the send DE).

It is not possible to do this without some "coding" . Your options are :

Update the Send Date extension you wish to use via SQL . Then you can use personalisation string

Ampscript (Lookup or LookUpOrderedRows)

Server Side JS

Guided Template Language ( moustache and handlebar templates)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to delve too far into Ampscript to be able to do some basic personalisation. The Lookup function is really all you need to get data from other data extensions.

```
%%[
VAR @var, @this
SET @this = [Email_Address]
SET @var = Lookup ("OtherDataExtension", "fieldyouwant", "Wherethisis...", @this)
]%%
```

This will retrieve the value of the field **fieldyouwant** from the **OtherDataExtension** where the **wherethisis** column is equal to the other variable (usually a subscriber key or email address).